Pagination query is not accepting variable
I am using next.js and apollo client to to query graphql api. I have following code for cursor based pagination.
  const GET_COMMENT_DATA = gql`
  query Comments($cursor: String, $limit: Int) {
    moreComments(cursor: $cursor, limit: $limit) {
      cursor
      comments {
        id
        author
        text
      }
    }
  }
`;
  const { data, fetchMore, error } = useSuspenseQuery(GET_COMMENT_DATA, {
    variables: {
     cursor:"",
     limit:10,
    },
  });

This code yields following error
 ⨯ ApolloError: Response not successful: Received status code 400
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
digest: "2545657766"

I think there is not any wrong with api and query because following code is working just fine
const GET_COMMENT_DATA = gql`
  query Comments {
    moreComments(cursor: "", limit: 10) {
      cursor
      comments {
        id
        author
        text
     }
    }
  }
`;
  const { data, fetchMore, error } = useSuspenseQuery(GET_COMMENT_DATA);

Consoling the data from second code where variable is not provided gives following output.
{
  moreComments: {
    __typename: 'MoreCommentsResponse',
    cursor: 'MTA=',
    comments: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ]
  }
}

I don't know why the variable is not working on first code. I have been stuck in this from past two days. I am new to apollo client please help.

I suspect that your server is treating an empty string as not a string and returning a 400 due to the variable not being of the right type. Try sending that first query with only the limit variable. cursor is optional anyway.
